# Jasmine Async Callback Timeouts Only on One Machine

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I apologize in advance for the wall of text, but this is a strange issue that I have not found any possible solutions for yet, nor has searching the web turned up anything else similar to this.

I have a few angular applications that I am testing with protractor.  I recently switched the database/application server that the tests were running against to a newer box that will strictly be used to run the automated tests, and am using the original box as a manual test bed.  All I had to change in the application were the SQL commands in the gruntfile (to properly backup and restore the databases), and the connection strings in protractor.conf.js.  I also made sure the APIServiceURL in the config.json is pointing to the proper new server URL.

Before switching to the new server, I could run the tests on my local machine with no issue, and all tests would pass.  Ever since switching to this new server, I am getting Jasmine timeouts, *but only on my local machine*.  If I run these tests on one of the build servers, they all run fine, and pass with no issues.  However, when running on my local machine, Chrome hangs with an app crash and I get the following in Git Shell:

```
' timestamp='2016-03-10T19:58:50.978']
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
##teamcity[testFailed name='should navigate to manage schedule templates screen' message='Error: Timeout - Asy
nc callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.'
```

These errors only start appearing after the first 10-12 tests have already passed, and always involve switching between URLs, for example going from the Home page to a Settings page.  I have tried testing with a browser.pause(), and I can reproduce the issue just by clicking on links over and over.  There are no errors in the Chrome console.  However, if I launch Chrome and manually browse to the application, I cannot reproduce the error.  This is leading me to believe that it has something specific to do with the version of Chrome that webdriver is spinning up on my local machine.  My local machine is running the latest version of Chrome, as are the build servers, and during the browser.pause(), I was able to confirm that webdriver is launching the same version of Chrome that I run when I browse to the application manually.

My Chrome args in the protractor.conf.js are --disable-web-security and --ignore-certificate-errors (we are using a self-signed IIS cert for testing purposes).  I originally thought there might be a rogue extension causing some havoc, so I ran it a few times with the --disable-extensions switch to no avail.

Grunt is running the appropriate ngmins, so the application is running minified, and there are no dependencies missing.

I have the following timeouts set in my protractor config:

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {
  defaultTimeoutInterval:60000
},

allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
```

An example of the test that is causing initial failure:

```
it('should navigate to manage states screen', function() {
    homePage.statesButton.click().then(function() {
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('states');
    });
});
```

The above test is the 6th and final test in that particular suite, and if I move it to being the first test in the suite, it passes, and the new last test becomes the point of failure, so it's not a problem with any one specific test.  I have tried commenting the test out, and the failures just crop up when it moves on to the next suite.  There is no discernible pattern that I can see, as sometimes it fails earlier in the process.  Also, other test suites pass just fine, such as the suite of tests used for login testing, and other suites fail earlier or later than expected.

Running protractor 2.1.0 and selenium standalone and chromedriver are both up-to-date, using webdriver-manager update.  My local machine is running Node version 4.4, and the build servers are all running Node version 4.2.  My local machine is Windows 7, the original test server was Windows Server 2008, and the new test server is Windows Server 2012.

I am just about at my wits' end with this.  Anybody out there have any ideas?

**EDIT:** After a couple other people were able to run the tests fine from their machines as well, I changed the tests to use http instead of https, removed the --ignore-certificate-error flag from the Chrome arguments, and the tests now run fine on my machine.  I'm not sure what the actual issue is, but it appears that running the tests against SSL on my machine is causing the issue.  I will need to do some research as to what setting on my machine could be causing this, but the tests seem to be working fine now.  If I come up with anything, I will share it here.